# Custom authentication overriding Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have my 2.5.4 grails version application secured by Spring Security and working very well. I need to change that and grant access to the user only if the reply of a rest service allows that. That is, instead of using the spring security functionality of asking for a username/password, I want to call a rest service (that I have already) and if this service replies that the user has access to the application, I want to grant access to this user.
As far as I understand, I need to override the auth method of LoginController of spring security core. Will I also need grails filters?
Could you please provide me with some advice on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in BootStrap.groovy running grails 3.1.9. Not sure it will help you, but it might be a starting point.

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder as SCH
...
SCH.context.authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(admin.username, admin.password, admin.authorities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [spring security rest plugin](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest) (version 1.5.3 for grails 2.5.x) and using JWTs to pass around the authentication?